# How do I supply an initial value to a text field?

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

I'd like to supply an initial value to a text field and redraw it with an empty value to clear the text. What's the best approach to do that with Flutter's APIs?

Answer (score 275):

You can use a `TextFormField` instead of `TextField`, and use the `initialValue` property. for example

```
TextFormField(initialValue: "I am smart")
```

Comment: For some reason I couldn't use this with a dynamic object. Ended up needing the controller.

Comment: This is only valid when a controller is not specified with a TextFormField. https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextFormField/TextFormField.htm

Comment: @AlexFallenstedt there is no need for this property when the controller is available

Comment: I think this is risky because when rebuilding your widget tree your text can be replace with initial value.

Answer (score 215):

(From the mailing list. I didn't come up with this answer.)

```
class _FooState extends State<Foo> {
  TextEditingController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = new TextEditingController(text: 'Initial value');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new TextField(
          // The TextField is first built, the controller has some initial text,
          // which the TextField shows. As the user edits, the text property of
          // the controller is updated.
          controller: _controller,
        ),
        new RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // You can also use the controller to manipuate what is shown in the
            // text field. For example, the clear() method removes all the text
            // from the text field.
            _controller.clear();
          },
          child: new Text('CLEAR'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess hint servers the same purpose.

Comment: Just wonder which mailing list did you refer to in the answer?

Comment: And how do we append / override textfield value into initial value?

Comment: Also, be sure to dispose _controller on the widget's dispose. It is recommended by Google. It ensures that the resources are freed up when not needed.

Answer (score 203):

You don't have to define a separate variable in the widget scope, just do it inline:

```
TextField(
  controller: TextEditingController()..text = 'Your initial value',
  onChanged: (text) => {},
)
```

Comment: What is meant by the double dots in "TextEditingController()..text"?

Comment: @RayLi It's called cascade operator. For info and example check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53136945/what-does-that-2-dots-mean-what-is-the-difference-between-1-and-2

Comment: Thanks!. This perfect for dynamic creation of widgets from lists of objects :)

Comment: @vovahost it's missing the dispose part, unfortunately.

Comment: This might be bad because you should dispose of TextEditingController's in the widget's dispose() method.

Comment: I am using Provider to provide initial Value to TextEditingController using the cascade approach but whenever I change the user gender let's say from 'Male' to 'Female' using ChangeNotifierProvider The TextFormField Data is being reset to initial Value Provided to the Controllers, is There any Approach that I can use.

Comment: Found the Solution in my case, declaring the TextEditingController to final was the Problem :)

Comment: this is the only one working for me. TYSM!

Comment: This worked for me since I'm using the bloc package.

Comment: @TravisReeder I think so too. But how "bad" it is? Will it cause memory leak?

Answer (score 70):

I've seen many ways of doing this on here. However I think this is a little more efficient or at least concise than the other answers.

```
TextField(
   controller: TextEditingController(text: "Initial Text here"),
)
```

Comment: The controller should be disposed!

Comment: Michael the controller is automatically disposed when the view is unloaded

Comment: @Kent Can you offer a reference for that statement about automatic disposal?

Answer (score 48):

> If you are using **TextEditingController** then set the text to it, like below

```
TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();


_controller.text = 'your initial text';

final your_text_name = TextFormField(
      autofocus: false,
      controller: _controller,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Hint Value',
      ),
    );
```

> and if you are not using any **TextEditingController** then you can directly use **initialValue** like below

```
final last_name = TextFormField(
      autofocus: false,
      initialValue: 'your initial text',
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Last Name',
      ),
    );
```

> For more reference [TextEditingController](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html)

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a good idea to set the initial value to the `text` property as per docs of `TextEditingController.text` property: Setting this will notify all the listeners of this TextEditingController that they need to update (it calls notifyListeners). For this reason, this value should only be set between frames, e.g. in response to user actions, not during the build, layout, or paint phases. (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController/text.html)

Answer (score 36):

This can be achieved using `TextEditingController`.

To have an initial value you can add

```dart
TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController(text: 'initial value');
```

or

If you are using `TextFormField` you have a `initialValue` property there. Which basically provides this `initialValue` to the widget automatically.

```dart
TextFormField(
  initialValue: 'initial value'
)
```

To clear the text you can use
`_controller.clear()` method.

Comment: You cannot have `controller` and `initialValue` both non-null for `TextFormField`

Answer (score 14):

If you want to handle multiple `TextInput`s as asked by @MRT in the comment to the accepted answer, you can create a function that takes an initial value and returns a `TextEditingController` like this:

```
initialValue(val) {
  return TextEditingController(text: val);
}
```

Then, set this function as the controller for the `TextInput` and supply its initial value there like this:

```
controller: initialValue('Some initial value here....')
```

You can repeat this for the other `TextInput`s.

Comment: ```controller: searchFieldController..text = viewModel.searchKeyword.value,``` :)

Comment: Can be used with ```TextField``` too.

Answer (score 10):

```
class _YourClassState extends State<YourClass> {
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.text = 'Your message';
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: _controller,
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Send message...'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
TextEdittingController _controller = new TextEdittingController(text: "your Text");
```

or

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _Controller.text = "Your Text";
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

If you use `TextEditingController` just use the line in your class.

```
TextEditingController txtController = TextEditingController(text: 'Initial value')

TextField(
  controller: txtController,
);
```

If you don't use `TextEditingController` just go for `initialValue`

```
TextFormField(
      initialValue: 'your initial text',
  );
```

**Full code**

```
class _TestScreen extends State<Test> {
  TextEditingController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = new TextEditingController(text: 'Initial value');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
       TextFormField(       // First method
          initialValue: "Initial text"
        ),
       TextField(       // Second method
          controller: _controller, // Controller has the initial value
        ),
        
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**inside class,**

```
  final usernameController = TextEditingController(text: 'bhanuka');
```

**TextField,**

```
   child: new TextField(
        controller: usernameController,
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 5):

Easy and Efficient way

Assign controller to your `TextFormField` or `TextField` and in `initState` you can initialise it to the initial value like this

```
_controller = TextEditingController(text: 'Your initial value');
```

Answer (score 5):

Since none of the answers mention it, the `TextEditingController` [should be disposed off after use](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes#listen-to-the-controller-for-changes). As in:

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  MyWidgetState createState() => MyWidgetState();
}

class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  final myController = TextEditingController(text: "Initial value");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: myController,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // dispose it here
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: How would one match the InputDecoration?

Answer (score 3):

1. When you are Using **TextEditingController**

If you use TextEditingController, set its text field to the desired value

```
TextEditingController txtController = TextEditingController()..text = 'Your initial text value'; 
TextField( controller: txtController ..... )
```

2. When you are Not Using **TextEditingController**

If you are not using the TextEditingContller, use the initialValue field directly from the TextField widget:

```
TextFormField( initialValue: "Your initial text value" )
```

Answer (score 3):

if you use text form field and pass data from previous page to next page text form field use this

```dart
class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {

  late final String fname;

    ProfilePage({required this.fname});

  @override
  State<ProfilePage> createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  final _form = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  
  late var FullNameController = TextEditingController(text: widget.fname);
  
}
```

Comment: What the `late` is for here?

Comment: This is just what I was looking for, where I passed a string between pages.

@Wiktor the `late` modifier allows the field to be initialized later, after its declaration. In this case, it avoids the error `The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer.`

Answer (score 2):

As for the above-mentioned answers all are right, but one thing is missing that I wanna add to it is how to customize the **style** of this default text of TextFormField.

```
TextEditingController textController = TextEditingController(text: '4');

 TextFormField(
    controller: textController,
     // This style property will customize the default controller text
    style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.white,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
   ),
    ),
```

For this scenario, I would prefer to use *TextEditingController* instead of *initialValue*, Because if you want to change it later or modify it, then textController will continuously listen for your TextFormField input changes.
This is my personal view, let me know if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code sample:

```
    TextFormField(
          controller: nameController?..text='Your initial value',
         
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do all of the above things but, if you want the API to show your data when its's get loaded it shows up like profile page. so here's the code:

```
TextEditingController _nameController = TextEditingController(); // initialize the controller
 // when API gets the data, do this:
 _nameController.text = response.data.fullName; or _nameController.text = "Apoorv Pandey"
```

I hope it clears everything. Happy coding!

Comment: This works for me but can we do it with focus node or using _initValue also?

Comment: I can't understand your question, sorry can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: yes like i am using focus node and _initvalue={ name: ''} in a name formtextfield  and I want my _initvalue['name'] to be prefilled by fetching the name from server so after using controller I got the name but I am asking can we do without controller also ?

Comment: As my experience you can't do that without controller, but you can use a variable of String type and pass in the label text  inside decoration of the text form field it will be prefilled, and when user click on it it will go up and will be empty

Comment: ok thanks earlier I was trying with initialValue and it didn't work out but I would go with the controller for the time being

Comment: Yeah sure, I hope I was able to help you. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
final TextEditingController _textFieldController = TextEditingController();
@override
void initState() {
  _textFieldController.text = "Hello";
  super.initState();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be replacing `TextField` to `TextFormField` because, we can use the property `initialValue` and avoid the complexity to manage state.

Using `TextEditingController`is not optimal because it needs to recreate a instance of `TextEditingController` just to pass a initial value. Additionally, how can you handle if you need to customize more and require access the text controller in other places ? It would be so confused