# How to fix Switch widget that can't change after set value in the Widget build?

Tags: flutter

Switch widget will properly work with these. But if I uncomment that section, Switch widget will freeze.
I need to set Switch initial value based on arguments condition. How to do that?

```
class BookingPageState extends State<BookingPage> {
  bool reqPickup = false; 

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /* priceData = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments;
    if(priceData) setState(() {reqPickup = true; }); */

    return Switch.adaptive(
      value: reqPickup,
      onChanged:(bool value) {
        setState(() {reqPickup = value; });
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how do you set the initial data of your switch because every time that you set a new state the build method executes again and set your variable with the screen args
You can solve this using the initState method of your statefulwidget like this

```
class BookingPageState extends State<BookingPage> {
      bool reqPickup = false; 
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
          priceData = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments;
          if (priceData != null && mounted)
            setState(() {
              reqPickup = true;
          }); 
        });
      }

      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Switch.adaptive(
          value: reqPickup,
          onChanged:(bool value) {
            setState(() {reqPickup = value; });
          }
        )
      }
    }
```

Comment: But how if I want to use priceData in the Widget build? For example, I added TextFormField(initialValue: priceData).

Comment: You need to use the controller and set the value like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43214271/how-do-i-supply-an-initial-value-to-a-text-field

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. I believe this is what you want. It is the minimum viable code, under 30 lines. I hope it works. Feel free to provide acknowledgement in the comment below.

```
class BookingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const BookingPage({super.key});
  static bool reqPickup = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext ctx, void Function(void Function()) setState) {
            final Object? object = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments;
            final bool priceData = (object ?? false) as bool;
            if (priceData) {
              reqPickup = true;
              setState(() {});
            } else {}
            return Switch.adaptive(
              value: reqPickup,
              onChanged: (bool value) {
                reqPickup = value;
                setState(() {});
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Very concise answer, but why all setState function are blank?

Comment: setState function will update the UI, even if it's blank. So, it means you can perform a few operations (e.g. update a variable or call another function) above the setState and then the setState. It'll work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Considering @sebastian-garzon comments, finally I found what I need. Thanks

```
class BookingPageState extends State<BookingPage> {
  bool reqPickup = false; 
  TextEditingController inputCtrl = TextEditingController();
    
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      priceData = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments;
      if (priceData != null && mounted){
        inputCtrl.text = priceData.price
        setState(() { reqPickup = true; }); 
      }
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
       children: [
         TextFormField(
           controller: inputCtrl
         ),
         Switch.adaptive(
           value: reqPickup,
           onChanged:(bool value) {
             setState(() {reqPickup = value; });
           }
         )
       ]
     }
   }
 }
```